# echo an array from mysql and in a table with defined rows and cols

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I have got an array from mysql, now I am trying to put it into a table with 4 columns using a while loop. My method is that when `$counter%4==0`, I echo `</tr>` so that every 4 items will be arranged in one row. But I can't get the result I want, so can anyone tell me where the problem is or offer me a better way to do this? Here is my code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<?php 

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_status='New' AND post_type='Facilities' AND       post_keywords='icon'";
$run1 = mysql_query($query1);

$counter=0;
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($run1)){

        $post_id = $row1['post_id'];
        $post_title = $row1['post_title'];
        $post_date = $row1['post_date'];
        $post_author = $row1['post_author'];
        $post_keywords = $row1['post_keywords'];
        $post_type =$row1['post_type'];

        $post_content = $row1['post_content'];
        $post_status =$row1['post_status'];

 if($counter%4==0){
 echo '<tr>';
 }          
 ?> 
 <td>//here is the content from the array
 <div id="<?php echo $post_id?>" class="FacItem" onmousedown="function onmousedown() {      fac_change('down','<?php echo $post_id?>') }" onmouseup="function onmouseup() { fac_change('up','<?php echo $post_id?>') }" onmouseover="function onmouseover() { fac_change('over','<?php echo $post_id?>') }" onmouseout="function onmouseout() { fac_change('out','<?php echo $post_id?>') }"><a href="?page_id=282"><?php echo   $post_content?></a></div>
 </td>

<?php
if($counter%4==0){
echo '</tr>';
}
$counter++;
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you're opening and closing the row at the same round of the loop

you need to rearrange this code:

```
<?php
    if($counter%4==0)
    {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $counter++;
```

to

```
<?php
    $counter++;
    if($counter%4==0)
    {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

So now, when the counter is 0, an new row is started, and then it becomes 1 before the close row if statement is executed... then for every 4th value, the counter becomes 4 (or a multiple of 4) just before the close row, the close row if statement is executed.

Since the counter is still a multiple of 4 the next time the loop executes, an opening  is made, but the counter becomes 1 after this, so no closing is called.

Example

```
Loop #    Counter at <tr> if stmt    Counter at </tr> if stmt
    1                0 <tr>               1
    2                1                    2
    3                2                    3    
    4                3                    4 </tr>
    5                4 <tr>               5
    6                5                    6
    7                6                    7    
    8                7                    8 </tr>
```

Comment: In the solution, you have posted, the close row element is added when $counter is 0, 4, 8, etc., which is not what the OP wants. He wants columns of 4 elements. So, the statement should check for $counter when it becomes 3, 7, 11, etc.

Comment: @Stoic This does indeed work (for me and for the person asking), maybe you don't understand my explanation properly. I'll update the explanation above. Please undo the down vote :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second conditional check is wrong. Reason being that you want to output a `</tr>` when the four items have been added. Currently, `</tr>` is being inserted on zeroth items (i.e. 0, 4, 8, etc.), instead. So, you should use `$counter % 4 == 3` there, rather, which will insert the `</tr>` element, correctly:

```
// process to follow when the new row is being started
if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
  // start `tr` element here..
  echo '<tr>';
  // your code ..
}

// process to follow when 4 items have been counted for
if ($counter % 4 == 3) {
  // end `tr` element here..
  echo '</tr>';
  // your code ..
}

$counter++;
```

Comment: This is also another way to do it :), or like I mentioned, put the ++counter above the close tr if statement. Either way is good.

Comment: No. Your solution does not output the correct html. See my comment.